# functional analysis on convergence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

What example can be given for as sequence $\{f_{n}\}\subset C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ of smooth functions of commpact support on $\mathbb{R}$ and a smooth $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})-C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ of not compact support such that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ $\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\{|f_{n}^{(k)}(x)-f^{(k)}(x)|\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: An example satisfying all the conditions you mention is given by $f=f_n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any $f$ that tends to $0$ at infinity and a smooth $f_n$ with compact support with $f_n(x)=f(x)$ with $x\in [-n,n]$. This certainly can be done (following the idea of the partitions of the unity).

Comment: I'm not native, in spanish are called "funciones meseta". I think in english are called "Plateau functions" and that is the idea to make such $f_n$:

http://ajpheart.physiology.org/content/ajpheart/291/4/H2003/F1.large.jpg?width=800&height=600&carousel=1